# Code formatting standard across various IDEs for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, code-formatting

I am working on an Angular project. Developers in my team are using various IDEs like WebStrorm, SublimeText or even Eclipse.

I wish to have some kind of code formatting rules defined for JavaScript defined which can be imported in WebStorm as well as other IDEs, but as I searched I could not found anything standard for this.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a plugin called [editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/). It supports all the major editors. You define the rules in a config file that sits in the root of the project repo.

Additionally, you can include [jsHint](http://www.jshint.com/install/) in your workflow/build process to check your code for  potentially problems and inconsistent formatting. It's fully configurable.